# efficiently extracting data from pandas dictionary column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column containing dictionaries, only some of whose keys are of interest.
I can convert the dict column to another df , then get the elements of interest:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[{'x':1,'y':2},{'x':3,'y':4,'z':10}],'b':[5,6]})
cols_of_interest = ['x','z']
df_dicts = pd.DataFrame(df.a.tolist())
df_dicts = df_dicts[cols_of_interest]
```

If the dictionaries are large and the columns of interest sparse, would I be better off applying a function to the dictionary column?  That way I can possibly avoid generating a bunch of unused interim columns.

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to
create a filter function

```py
def filter_keys(x,cols_of_interest):
    new_dict={}
    for keys in x:
        if keys in cols_of_interest:
            new_dict[keys]=x[keys]
    return new_dict
```

and filter the relevant keys as

```py
cols_of_interest=['x','z']
df['c']=df['a'].apply(lambda x:filter_keys(x,cols_of_interest))
```

created a new column c with the filtered elements only.

```
    a   b   c
0   {'y': 2, 'x': 1}    5   {'x': 1}
1   {'y': 4, 'z': 10, 'x': 3}   6   {'z': 10, 'x': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) to extract the values associated with columns of interest and create a new `DataFrame` from these values:

```
cols = ['x', 'z']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.a.str.get(col) for col in cols).T.set_axis(cols, 1)
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
     x     z
0  1.0   NaN
1  3.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

(1) `.apply`:

```py
df_dicts=df['a'].apply(pd.Series)[cols_of_interest]
```

Outputs:

```py
     x     z
0  1.0   NaN
1  3.0  10.0
```

(2) alternatively using `.str` referrer:

```py
df_dicts=pd.concat([df['a'].str[col] for col in cols_of_interest], axis=1)
df_dicts.columns=cols_of_interest
```

Outputs:

```py
   x     z
0  1   NaN
1  3  10.0
```